# Looping links in csv file using selenium in python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to open a .csv file, and open link in .csv file with selenium, and loop through links in .csv file. I am new to Selenium . I can easily  do it in beautiful soup.Can you please guide me through right direction.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import requests

contents =[]

filename = 'link_business_filter.csv'

def copy_json():
    with open('vendors_info_bangkok.json',"a") as wt:
        for x in script3:
            wt.write(x)
            wt.close()
            return

with open(filename,'rt') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        links = row[0]
        contents.append(links)

for link in contents:
    url_html = requests.get(link)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    for link_loop in url_html:

       open = browser.get(link_loop)

       source = browser.page_source
       data = bs(source,"html.parser")
       body = data.find('body')
       script = body
       x_path = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div'
       script2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
       script3 = script2.text
       print(script3)
       copy_json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First install selenium:

  ```
  pip install selenium
  ```
- Then according to your `os` install [`chromediver`](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) then test it by going to folder you have kept the driver and open terminal and type `chromedriver`, if there's no error then it works.
- Then in your code you need to provide **`executable_path`** for the `chromdriver`

In you Code:

```
....code...


for link in contents:
    url_html = requests.get(link)

    path to chromdriver = 'C:/Users/chromedriver.exe'    #<-- you can keep this file anywhere you wish

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'path_to_chromdriver')    #<-- you can also give the path directly here
    for link_loop in url_html:


    ...code...
```

Comment: It is working only problem right now is that it is n't moving through other links in my .csv file @ans2human

Comment: okay, could you print the `contents` list and check if it contains links that you need to loop through.

Comment: @ans2humans problem is solved it can now thanks, but now opening multiple chrome windows is big mess as I have around 100 links. Is it possible to have multiple tabs in Chrome to open rather different chrome windows opening !!

Comment: please accept this answer for other readers and create a new question for your query.

Comment: why did you accept this answer if it doesn't answer the question you asked?